# Cannot connect to mysql with 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, mysql, database

With the following code I can connect to mysql:
`mysql_connect("localhost","username","");`

But if I change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` I get the following error:

Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (13)

Why doesn't it work with 127.0.0.1?

Comment: This should be a "Permission denied" issue.

Comment: What platform are you using, windows or unix?

Comment: @Jürgen Thelen — Why should it?

Comment: @Quentin: error 13 usually means "Permission denied". At least this is what perror 13 outputs on my system.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`localhost` is special cased and uses UNIX sockets instead of TCP/IP. `127.0.0.1` doesn't get that special handling.

See [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html):

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of 127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also specify the connection protocol explicitly, even for localhost, by using the --protocol=TCP option.

If it doesn't work when you use TCP/IP then the database probably isn't listening on the network. This is generally a good thing as it enhances security (not that listening on 127.0.0.1 exposes any problems, but listening on all interfaces gives more opportunity for attacks).

If you really want to allow connections via the network, then see [skip-networking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-options.html).

Answer (score 1):

have you got an entry in your hosts file mapping 127.0.0.7 to localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than 1 mysql servers installed/running on your system? If so, please specify the port number of the mysql server you are trying to access like 127.0.0.1:3306,127.0.0.1:8889 etc.

If you do not know whether there are any other mysql server instances running on your system also, please specify the port.

Comment: Does running a second instance of MySQL prevent the first from running on the default port now?

Comment: No, it does not prevent from running but it may be unable to access the mysql server without mentioning the port number even when it is running on default port when more than 1 instance is running

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to access it when you add the privileges for `'root'@'127.0.0.1'` in the `"USER_PRIVILEGES"` table in the `"information_schema"` database

Comment: No. If that was the problem the error would be "Access denied for user", not "cannot connect"

Answer (score 0):

You might also try disabling SELINUX