# Two MySQL local server connect errors

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to connect the MySQL database that is on my Mac to a website, I get the following error:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

That is when I put `localhost` as the servername.

When I put `127.0.0.1` as the servername, I receive the following error:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (13)
```

The following Stack questions did not work for me:
[Cannot connect to mysql with 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347993/cannot-connect-to-mysql-with-127-0-0-1)
[error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq)

Comment: you need to start your mysql server

Comment: @YourCommonSense how do you do that?

Comment: Plug it into the wall and press the big red power button... ... ... ... ... (...'ry)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check the status of mysql server:
is that runs?
the difference between tow error is based on allowed mysql connection port over network.