# How to connect to MySQL with sockets via terminal?

Tags: mysql, sockets, tcp

My /etc/hosts file has `127.0.0.1 localhost` line. When I try to connect to MySQL with `mysql -u root -h localhost -p` I get the `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` error. However, when I connect using 127.0.0.1, it works fine or using `localhost` with `--protocol=TCP`.

I [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347993/cannot-connect-to-mysql-with-127-0-0-1) that Unix treats host name `localhost` special and uses socket file instead of TCP/IP. Is it possible to connect to MySQL with socket file via terminal to not allow connections via the network?

Comment: Did you change file permission of mysql folder using sudo chmod. Wild Guess !!

Comment: No, I didn't. It's just a default XAMPP installation in /opt/lampp